# Angular-Nodejs SSL

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, angular8

I wanted to migrate my Angular - Node js server to https. I have generated certificates from OpenSSL. I added them to both Node js server.ts and angular.json. I am facing couple of problems:-
1). I am able to run Angular app without the certificates and also with the wrong certificates. I am not sure why its allowing without handshake? What is the use of adding cert in angular if it allows without certs?
2). I want to encrypt my password field, how can i encrypt password at Angular with my certificate and decrypt at Nodejs with the key.

Updating the question as i see how to read the file.

Comment: JavaScript has a FileReader, so Angular has a FileReader.

Answer (score 0):

Yes angular has a file reader

Eg : let fileReader = new FileReader();

This can help you [Running Angular CLI over HTTPS with a Trusted Certificate](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a)

Comment: yes, i have already read that but my question is if i dont provide sslCert and sslKey than also my angular app connects to Node server. So then whats the use of specifying Cert and key?

Comment: Have you made the changes to the angular/package.json like....

"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build",
        "ssl": true,
        "sslKey": "path to .key",
        "sslCert": "path to .crt"
    },
    ...
}

Comment: yes, i made the changes but its working without the changes as well. I have another Nodejs backend where this certs are deployed. Is there any chances cert are downloaded i browser with that Node js?